# Flowbite dropdown not working in laravel/vue project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a dropdown toggle in my list from a flowbite table, other js functionalities work but this dropdown not

dropdown looks like this:
copied from Flowbite's default table (https://flowbite.com/blocks/application/advanced-tables/)

```
    <td class="px-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-end">
        <button id="apple-imac-27-dropdown-button" data-dropdown-toggle="apple-imac-27-dropdown" class="inline-flex items-center p-0.5 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-lg focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-100" type="button">
            <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewbox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M6 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM12 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM16 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" />
            </svg>
        </button>
        <div id="apple-imac-27-dropdown" class="hidden z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600">
            <ul class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="apple-imac-27-dropdown-button">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Show</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button
                        @click="openEditModal(product)"
                        href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Edit</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="py-1">
                <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

I have setup the js in my tailwind.config.js like so:

```
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.vue',
        "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js",
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [forms,  require('flowbite/plugin')],
};
```

I've also inited flowbite like so:

```
onMounted(() => {
    initFlowbite();
})
```